# android: create files under a subdirectory in /data/data/<package>/files

Tags: android, file, subdirectory

I'm trying to create files under a subdirectory in `/data/data/package_name/files`.
For example, `/data/data/package_name/files/folder1/file1.txt`. This is my code:

```
FileOutputStream fos;
String path = getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + folderName + "/" + String.valueOf(i+1) + ".txt";
try
{
    File f = new File(path);
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    f.createNewFile();
    fos = new FileOutputStream(path, false);
    fos.write(array[i].getBytes());
    fos.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I don't know if I have the permission though. Will the files under `/data/data/package_name/files` be still available when user restarts the application? I don't want user to see my files, so writing to sdcard won't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileOutputStream fos;
File f = getFilesDir();
try{
    String fileName = "test.txt";
    String filePath = f.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+fileName;
    fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    fos.write(array[i].getBytes());
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        fos.close();
    }catch(IOException e1){}
}
```

This worked for me.